# Java REGEX code to validate Indian language characters not working?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, utf-8

Why the following code not working(resulting false) with Indian languages?

```
System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("అనువాద")
                .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\\p{L}+"));

System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("स्वागत")
                .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\\p{L}+"));

System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("நல்வரவு")
                .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\\p{L}+"));
```

All the above code returns false. What is the problem with this regex? How to validate any unicode character in the world?

Comment: You should do `"అనువాద".matches("\\p{L}+")`. Further ensure that both the editor and the compiler use the same character set (best UTF-8).

Comment: Hi Joop, I made sure the compiler and editor uses UTF-8. But still "అనువాద".matches("\\p{L}+") results false.

Comment: Use `"(\\p{L}|\\p{M})+"`, or better @stema `"[\\pL\\pM]+"`, also counting diacritical marks as valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\p{Letter}` only captures letters but you also need marks, which you can capture with `\p{Mark}`.

```
System.out.println("स्वागत".matches("[\\pL\\pM]+"));
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much? Will the same work with all international characters? Could you please explain me about marks? Thanks again.

Comment: In short a mark is special character that is combined with an existing character such as an umlaut. There is a lot more to it, I recommend reading this article if you need to understand more. http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: Im wondering why it accepts all inputs. Following code returns ture.  System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("स्वागत1@_!^#$%^&*!()_+")
     .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\\PL+\\PM+"));

Comment: The code has been updated after several suggestions, it should work as intended now. See also Joop Eggen's comment.

Comment: @suren: Your problem is, that `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("स्वागत1@_!^#$%^&*!()_+") .asCharBuffer().toString()` changes the original string, because Java chars are UTF-16.

Comment: Everyone thanks for your help. I have one more confusion. Why does the regex \pL+\pM+ not work with English?

Why does the below first example results false wherein the second one results true?

System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("suren") .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\PL+\PM+"));

System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("स्वागत") .asCharBuffer().toString().matches("\PL+\PM+"));

Basically i need a regular expression to restrict only unicode characters(any language in the world) in a string.

Comment: @suren, read the answer again, it has been corrected, `\pL+\pM+` is wrong and works only accidentally with your test string.